# Repopulate carousel with AJAX

Tags: jquery, carousel

$(function(){

```
function showDisplay(items){

  $.get('test'+items+'.html', function(data) {
    $('.carousel ul').empty();      
    $('.carousel ul').html(data);
    $("div.example-2").carousel({ direction: "vertical", dispItems:5 , pagination:true });
    $('<div class="nextGroup">next</div>').appendTo($('.content-pag')).click( function(){
       showDisplay('2');
    });
});

  showDisplay('1');

});
```

I have this code. The idea is repopulate carousel with new items added by AJAX, but for some reason when I call the NEXT button the carousel crashes. I'm using jQuery Carousel 0.9.5.

.content-pag is generated by carousel

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this:

```
$('.carousel ul').empty;
```

should be this:

```
$('.carousel ul').empty();
```